# why js closest method not find sibling element?

Tags: javascript, html, dom, search, closest

**Note:** as far as i know that `closest()` method searches up the DOM tree for the closest element which matches a specified CSS selector.

When i click on `margin` space between two `li` element .. it's return null...
but if i replace `margin-bottom: 15px;` with `padding-bottom`... everything is okay...

***CSS Code***

```
.amenities-filters-inner ul li{
    margin-bottom: 15px;
}
```

**Image** if i click on red mark area.. it's not found sibling `li` element ..

[image]

**Example Code**

```js
   document.querySelectorAll(".amenities-filters-inner ").forEach(function(item){
    item.addEventListener("click",function(e){
        e.preventDefault();

        let element = null;
        element = e.target.closest(".amenity_id");
        // element = e.target.querySelector(".amenity_id");
         element = element.children[0].children[1];
         element.checked == true ? element.checked = false :  element.checked =true;
       
        let dataId =  + element.getAttribute('data-id');
        console.log(element)
        console.log(dataId)
       
    })
})
```

```css
 .amenities-filters-inner{
        
            border: 2px dashed royalblue;
            max-width: 300px;
            padding: 1rem;
        }
        ul{
            list-style: none;
            width: 100%;
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
           
        }
        li{
            border: 2px solid rgb(133, 129, 129);
            padding: 3px;
        }


.amenities-filters-inner:last-child{
    margin-bottom: 0;
}

.amenities-filters-inner ul li{
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}
.amenities-filters-inner ul li:last-child{
    margin-bottom: 0;
}

.check {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: space-between;
    position: relative;
    padding-left: 31px;
    margin-bottom: 0;
    padding-right: 0;
    cursor: pointer;
    font-size: 14px; 
    color: #646464;
}
.check  strong{
    color: #969696;
    font-size: 14px; 
    font-weight: 400;
}

.check input {
    position: absolute;
    opacity: 0;
    cursor: pointer;
}


.checkmark {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    height: 17px;
    width: 17px;
    background-color: #fff ;
    border-color: #646464;
    border-style:solid;
    border-width:1px;
    border-radius: 2px;
}

.check input:checked ~ .checkmark {
    background-color: #fff;
    border-color: #007FEB;
}
.checkmark:after {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    display: none;
}
.check input:checked ~ .checkmark:after {
    display: block;
}
.check .checkmark:after {
    left: 5px;
    top: 1px;
    width: 5px;
    height: 10px;
    border: solid ;
    border-color:#007FEB;
    border-width: 0 2px 2px 0;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(45deg);
    transform: rotate(45deg);
}
```

```html
   <div class="amenities-filters-inner">
            <ul>
                <li class="amenity_id">
                    <label class="check ">One <strong>One</strong>
                        <input type="checkbox" class="amenity_data" data-id="1" name="is_name">
                        <span class="checkmark"></span>
                    </label>
                </li>
                <li class="amenity_id">
                    <label class="check ">Two <strong>Two</strong>
                        <input type="checkbox" class="amenity_data" data-id="2"name="is_name">
                        <span class="checkmark"></span>
                    </label>
                </li>
<li class="amenity_id">
                    <label class="check ">Three<strong>Three</strong>
                        <input type="checkbox" class="amenity_data" data-id="3"name="is_name">
                        <span class="checkmark"></span>
                    </label>
                </li>
              
               
            </ul>
        </div>
```

Comment: If you click inside the margin, the event target is the `<ul>`, from where no [*closest*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/closest) element that matches `.amenity_id` is available.

Comment: @Yoshi better you can put as an answer ...

Comment: I'm not quite sure how to answer, because I can't see what your intention is actually.

Comment: @Yoshi you find out the actual problem ... it's your credit....i try to delete this question... it's giving me alert you can not delete ...

Comment: Personally I think both given answers are correct in their statements, so a third answer feels unnecessary (imho).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`.closest()` method only traverses parents, not children.

That area is in container `.amenities-filters-inner` not inside list element, so it won't find the `.amenities-id`.

Change the background color of container to debug.

```
.amenities-filters-inner{
  background: red;
}
```

If you don't want gaps between list items, don't use margin. Use `padding-top` and `padding-bottom` instead.

> The `closest()` method traverses the Element and its parents (heading toward the document root) until it finds a node that matches the provided selector string. Will return itself or the matching ancestor. If no such element exists, it returns `null`.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/closest

Answer (score 2):

By clicking inside the red marked area, you are clicking **between** the two `<li>` elements which means you are inside the `<ul>` element. Calling `closest()` on `target` brings you up to `<div>`; what you are looking for is a child inside (that is, down) the `<ul>` element. Try changing

```
element = e.target.closest(".amenity_id");
```

in your script to

```
element = e.target.querySelector(".amenity_id");
```

and see if it works.