# How will I target the nearest child element aspect of on click area in vanilla JS?

Tags: javascript, dom, search, selector

Based on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65181834/why-js-closest-method-not-find-sibling-element), another question raised in my mind. While both questions have almost similar, they are different.

**how will i target nearest child element aspect of on click area in vanilla js means:**  i will click on outer side of `li` element and inner side of `ul` element and nearest `li` will be the target ..below Example Code..

**Note:** Jquery `find` method can not resolve the issue. I tried it, but it repeats the same element all time.

**What I tried to achieve**

*From below picture red mark area:*  when I click on red mark area nearest `li` will be the target element. That is what I want... I did not resolve the issue. I think everything is possible ..there are so many selectors available in `css` & `js`...

[image]

***Example Code***

```js
$(".amenities-filters-inner").each(function(i, el) {
  $(el).on("click", function(event) {
    event.preventDefault()
    var element = null;
    element = $(event.target).closest(".amenity_id");
    element = $(element).children().children().next();

    if ($(element).checked == true)
      $(element).checked = false;
    else {
      $(element).checked = true;
    }

    let dataId = null;
    if (element.hasClass('amenity_data')) {
      dataId = $(element).data('index');

    } else {
      element = $(event.target).find(".amenity_id");
      element = $(element).children().children().next();
      dataId = $(element).data('index');

    }

    console.log('$ el:' + element)
    console.log('$ index:' + dataId)
  })
});

document.querySelectorAll(".amenities-filters-inner ").forEach(function(item) {
  item.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    let element = null;
    element = e.target.closest(".amenity_id");
    // element = e.target.querySelector(".amenity_id");
    element = element.children[0].children[1];
    element.checked == true ? element.checked = false : element.checked = true;

    let dataId = element.getAttribute('data-index');
    console.log('js el' + element)
    console.log('js index ' + dataId)
  })
})
```

```css
.amenities-filters-inner {
  border: 2px dashed royalblue;
  max-width: 300px;
  padding: 1rem;
}

ul {
  list-style: none;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

li {
  border: 2px solid rgb(133, 129, 129);
  padding: 3px;
}

.amenities-filters-inner {
  border: 2px dashed royalblue;
  max-width: 300px;
  padding: 1rem;
}

ul {
  list-style: none;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

li {
  border: 2px solid rgb(133, 129, 129);
  padding: 3px;
}

.amenities-filters-inner:last-child {
  margin-bottom: 0;
}

.amenities-filters-inner ul li {
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.amenities-filters-inner ul li:last-child {
  margin-bottom: 0;
}

.check {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
  position: relative;
  padding-left: 31px;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  padding-right: 0;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size: 14px;
  color: #646464;
}

.check strong {
  color: #969696;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: 400;
}

.check input {
  position: absolute;
  opacity: 0;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.checkmark {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 17px;
  width: 17px;
  background-color: #fff;
  border-color: #646464;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 1px;
  border-radius: 2px;
}

.check input:checked~.checkmark {
  background-color: #fff;
  border-color: #007FEB;
}

.checkmark:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  display: none;
}

.check input:checked~.checkmark:after {
  display: block;
}

.check .checkmark:after {
  left: 5px;
  top: 1px;
  width: 5px;
  height: 10px;
  border: solid;
  border-color: #007FEB;
  border-width: 0 2px 2px 0;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(45deg);
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="amenities-filters-inner">
  <ul>
    <li class="amenity_id">
      <label class="check ">One <strong>One</strong>
        <input type="checkbox" class="amenity_data" data-index="1" name="is_name">
        <span class="checkmark"></span>
      </label>
    </li>
    <li class="amenity_id">
      <label class="check ">Two <strong>Two</strong>
        <input type="checkbox" class="amenity_data" data-index="2" name="is_name">
        <span class="checkmark"></span>
      </label>
    </li>
    <li class="amenity_id">
      <label class="check ">Three <strong>Three</strong>
        <input type="checkbox" class="amenity_data" data-index="3" name="is_name">
        <span class="checkmark"></span>
      </label>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: When a user clicks the red area between 1st & 2nd `li`s, which one of these two should be selected?

Comment: @OfirD  nearest one  be selected depend on click area

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this achieves what you're after:

- Note that clicking close to one checkbox and then close to another checkbox will check both checkboxes, but you can change that of course.

```js
document.querySelectorAll(".amenities-filters-inner").forEach(function(item) {
  item.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    let element = null;
    var lis = document.getElementsByClassName("amenity_id");
    for (var i = 0; i < lis.length; i++) {
        var current = lis[i];
      var next = lis[i+1];
      var currentBox = current.getBoundingClientRect();
      var nextBox = next && next.getBoundingClientRect();
      if (clickedBeforeFirstCheckbox(e, i == 0, currentBox) ||  
            clickedAfterLastCheckbox(e, i == lis.length-1, currentBox) ||
          clickedInBetween(e, currentBox, nextBox)) {
          setCheckboxByDistance(e, current, next, currentBox, nextBox);
            break;
      }
    }
  })
});

function clickedBeforeFirstCheckbox(e, isFirst, currentBox) {
    return isFirst && e.clientY < currentBox.y;
}
function clickedAfterLastCheckbox(e, isLast, currentBox) {
    return isLast && e.clientY > currentBox.y;
}
function clickedInBetween(e, currentBox, nextBox) {
    return e.clientY > currentBox.y && 
          e.clientY < nextBox.y;
}

function setCheckboxByDistance(e, current, next, currentBox, nextBox) {
  var diffToCurrent = 
    Math.abs(e.clientY - (currentBox.y + (currentBox.height / 2)));
  var diffToNext =  nextBox ? 
    Math.abs(e.clientY - (nextBox.y + (nextBox.height / 2))) : 
    Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER;
  if (diffToCurrent < diffToNext) {
    var checkbox = current.querySelector('input');
    checkbox.checked = !checkbox.checked;
  } else {
    var checkbox = next.querySelector('input');
    checkbox.checked = !checkbox.checked;
  }
}
```

```css
.amenities-filters-inner {
  border: 2px dashed royalblue;
  max-width: 300px;
  padding: 1rem;
}

ul {
  list-style: none;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

li {
  border: 2px solid rgb(133, 129, 129);
  padding: 3px;
}

.amenities-filters-inner {
  border: 2px dashed royalblue;
  max-width: 300px;
  padding: 1rem;
}

ul {
  list-style: none;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

li {
  border: 2px solid rgb(133, 129, 129);
  padding: 3px;
}

.amenities-filters-inner:last-child {
  margin-bottom: 0;
}

.amenities-filters-inner ul li {
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.amenities-filters-inner ul li:last-child {
  margin-bottom: 0;
}

.check {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
  position: relative;
  padding-left: 31px;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  padding-right: 0;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size: 14px;
  color: #646464;
}

.check strong {
  color: #969696;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: 400;
}

.check input {
  position: absolute;
  opacity: 0;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.checkmark {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 17px;
  width: 17px;
  background-color: #fff;
  border-color: #646464;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 1px;
  border-radius: 2px;
}

.check input:checked~.checkmark {
  background-color: #fff;
  border-color: #007FEB;
}

.checkmark:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  display: none;
}

.check input:checked~.checkmark:after {
  display: block;
}

.check .checkmark:after {
  left: 5px;
  top: 1px;
  width: 5px;
  height: 10px;
  border: solid;
  border-color: #007FEB;
  border-width: 0 2px 2px 0;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(45deg);
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}
```

```html
<div class="amenities-filters-inner">
  <ul>
    <li class="amenity_id">
      <label class="check ">One <strong>One</strong>
        <input type="checkbox" class="amenity_data" data-index="1" name="is_name">
        <span class="checkmark"></span>
      </label>
    </li>
    <li class="amenity_id">
      <label class="check ">Two <strong>Two</strong>
        <input type="checkbox" class="amenity_data" data-index="2" name="is_name">
        <span class="checkmark"></span>
      </label>
    </li>
    <li class="amenity_id">
      <label class="check ">Three <strong>Three</strong>
        <input type="checkbox" class="amenity_data" data-index="3" name="is_name">
        <span class="checkmark"></span>
      </label>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Firstly thanks for response & giving time to resolve the issue..i am happy with your answer & vote up. most probably i will reward you  on time if anyone  can not resolve only vanilla js . if you can resolve it only vanilla js or both way (jquery & vanilla js) .there will be no scope to skip you answer...

Comment: Converting to vanilla only requires few minor changes, I'll update my answer later.

Answer (score 2):

There are two approaches.

The first is to detect where the click occurred:

```
window.onclick = function(event)
{
 if (event.which && event.which==1)
 {
  console.log(event.clientX);
  console.log(event.clientY);
 }
}
```

Then you could in this oddball attempt iterate through the

```
var label = document.getElementsByTagName('label');

for (var i = 0; i < label.length; i++)
{
 console.log(label[i].getBoundingClientRect());
}
```

However that would be pointless because:

1. You're just guessing that the user *might* have intended to choose an option.
2. It ignores the fact that the GUI (graphic user interface) is not properly styled for usability.
3. Possibly failed to ask, "Does this help the client?"

Having some `margin` between form fields is acceptable. If you feel that people are having a difficult time clicking on them either add `padding`, increase the `font-size` or *do both*.